# Pushing the top most object in an SVG container to the bottom

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js, svg

I know what I want to accomplish but I don't know how to go about it.

**Background:** I have an interactive report, using D3, that uses circles to provide a visual reference to application usage by user location on top of a rendered map of the US by zip code. In places, these circles overlap, obscuring those underneath and preventing those circles underneath from receiving events, like mouseover for example. This creates a stack of circles.

**Objective:** I want to be able to click on a circle to push it to the bottom of the stack, though not beneath any background object that makes up the map. Or, as in this sample, not behind the .bgCircle.

Here is some sample code I put together in JSFiddle to illustrate the issue.

**The CSS:**

```
.bgCircle {
  fill: blue;
  opacity: .25
}

.popCircle {
  fill: green;
  opacity: 0.5;
  stroke: black;
  stroke-width: 1px;
}

svg {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

**The HTML**

```
<svg width="500" height="500">
  <g>
    <circle class="bgCircle" cx="250" cy="250" r="250" />
    <circle id="A" class="popCircle" cx="200" cy="200" r="100" />
    <circle id="B" class="popCircle" cx="300" cy="200" r="100" />
    <circle id="C" class="popCircle" cx="300" cy="300" r="100" />
    <circle id="D" class="popCircle" cx="200" cy="300" r="100" />
  </g>
</svg>
```

**The JavaScript**

```
d3.selectAll('.popCircle')
  .on('click', function(d) {
    var text = 'force circle ' + d3.select(this).attr('id') + ' to bottom of the popCircle stack but above the bgCircle';
    alert(text);
  });
```

**Sample Project**

https://jsfiddle.net/MissAmberClark/ssghj37v/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `selection.lower()` or `selection.raise()` in d3v4 to move things up or down in the DOM (within the parent element).  `selection.lower()` will place an element at the bottom of its parent, while `selection.raise()` will place an element at the top of its parent. These methods will therefore change the layering of svg elements as the ordering of the DOM sets the ordering of SVG elements.

So, in order to do this easily, the background elements should be in a separate `<g>` so that they remain unaffected. Then, just raise or lower elements on click as needed (only the topmost element will trigger with each click event in the snippet):

```js
d3.selectAll("circle")
  .on("click",function() {
    d3.select(this).lower();
  })
```

```css
#A { fill: orange; }
#B { fill: steelblue; }
#C { fill: pink; }
#D { fill: lawngreen; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.5.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg width="500" height="500">
  <g>
    <circle class="bgCircle" cx="250" cy="250" r="250" />
  </g>
  
  <g>
    <circle id="A" class="popCircle" cx="200" cy="200" r="100" />
    <circle id="B" class="popCircle" cx="300" cy="200" r="100" />
    <circle id="C" class="popCircle" cx="300" cy="300" r="100" />
    <circle id="D" class="popCircle" cx="200" cy="300" r="100" />
  </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: Awesome! I need to use d3 v4 as lower() isn't supported in v3. This means fun times ahead updating my report. Otherwise, this is perfect.

Comment: @amber It's a good idea to update your code to v4. However, if you don't have *fun times* doing that, check my answer for v3, which complements Andrew's answer.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado And fun times it was not. I'm sure what's going on with the v4 library but the map is being generated with negative x values that cause it to render outside of the SVG.

Answer (score 1):

You should isolate the background circle in a separate group. This makes things easier.

Svg element are drawn in sequence so the first element will be behind everyone else.
From your question it was unclear if you wanted the circle to be drawn in the back or put it in the last spot in the childeNode array. I added both solutions.

```js
d3.selectAll('.popCircle')
  .on('click', function(d) {
    var parent = this.parentNode;
    parent.removeChild(this);
    
    //Insert behind
    parent.insertBefore(this, parent.firstChild);
    
    //Insert in front
    //parent.appendChild(this);
  });
```

```css
.bgCircle {
  fill: blue;
  opacity: .25
}

.popCircle {
  fill: green;
  opacity: 0.5;
  stroke: black;
  stroke-width: 1px;
}

svg {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg width="500" height="500">
  <g>
    <circle class="bgCircle" cx="250" cy="250" r="250" />
  </g>
  
  <g>
    <circle id="A" class="popCircle" cx="200" cy="200" r="100" />
    <circle id="B" class="popCircle" cx="300" cy="200" r="100" />
    <circle id="C" class="popCircle" cx="300" cy="300" r="100" />
    <circle id="D" class="popCircle" cx="200" cy="300" r="100" />
  </g>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a solution for D3 v3.x, using vanilla JavaScript:

```
d3.selectAll("circle")
    .on("click", function() {
        var firstChild = this.parentNode.firstChild;
        this.parentNode.insertBefore(this, firstChild);
    })
```

Actually, the hint for doing this in D3 v3 is in [D3 v4 API](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection#selection_lower) itself! It says:

> selection.lower(): Re-inserts each selected element, in order, as the first child of its parent. Equivalent to:
>
> ```
> selection.each(function() {
>     this.parentNode.insertBefore(this, this.parentNode.firstChild);
> });
> ```

Here is the demo (I'm using [@Andrew's SVG](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45443007/5768908) here):

```js
d3.selectAll("circle")
  .on("click", function() {
    var firstChild = this.parentNode.firstChild;
    this.parentNode.insertBefore(this, firstChild);
  })
```

```css
#A {
  fill: orange;
}

#B {
  fill: steelblue;
}

#C {
  fill: pink;
}

#D {
  fill: lawngreen;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<svg width="500" height="500">
  <g>
    <circle class="bgCircle" cx="250" cy="250" r="250" />
  </g>
  <g>
    <circle id="A" class="popCircle" cx="200" cy="200" r="100" />
    <circle id="B" class="popCircle" cx="300" cy="200" r="100" />
    <circle id="C" class="popCircle" cx="300" cy="300" r="100" />
    <circle id="D" class="popCircle" cx="200" cy="300" r="100" />
  </g>
</svg>
```